# Is $\exp(x)$ the same as $e^x$?

Tags: notation, exponential-function, exponentiation

For homework I have to find the derivative of $\text {exp}(6x^5+4x^3)$ but I am not sure if this is equivalent to $e^{6x^5+4x^3}$ If there is a difference, what do I do to calculate the derivative of it?

Comment: There is no difference; they are alternative notations for the same thing.

Comment: It is just a matter of notation. For instance, if the power is a long polynomial we use $\exp$ so we will not get confused. This notation helps avoiding mistake.

Comment: Why didn't you ask the person who set the homework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/137499/37903

Comment: why so many upvotes?

Comment: @zed111 At first I agreed with you - too many upvotes. But scanning the answers shows that it is in fact an interesting question, though perhaps more interesting than the OP knew.

Comment: Also, it was featured as a hot network question; that tends to unleash a deluge of upvotes.

Comment: @zed111 Why not? If people *want* to upvote, for whatever reason, they're allowed to.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Yes. They are the same thing.

When exponents get really really complicated, mathematicians tend to start using $\exp(\mathrm{stuff})$ instead of $e^{\mathrm{stuff}}$.

For example: $e^{x^5+2^x-7}$ is kind of hard to read. So instead one might write: $\exp(x^5+2^x-7)$.

Note: For those who use Maple or other computer algebra systems, `e^x` is not usually the same as `exp(x)`. In Maple, `e^x` is the *variable* $e$ raised to the *variable* $x$ power whereas `exp(x)` is Euler's number $e$ raised to the $x$ power.

Comment: Agreed, they are two different ways of looking at the same thing... one way $e^x$ kind of the "mathy" way to view it, and $\text{exp}(x)$ is more the "programatical" way to view it.

Comment: @TravisJ It has nothing to do with programming and everything to do with the clarity of written mathematics, as the answer you're commenting on makes clear.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, by "programatical" I meant that $\text{exp}(x)$ emphasizes that you have a function, named exp() and the input to that function is $x$ (or whatever else...).  It is a convenient side effect that functional notation is sometimes easier to read than other notation.

Comment: @TravisJ: Functions are about the "mathiest" thing there is; it's bizarre to log onto a math site and tell mathematicians that functions are "programatical" instead of "mathy".

Comment: @ruakh, this is true, but in that vein any aspect of computing is fundamentally just applied mathematics.  I'm not trying to say it isn't mathematical, it's just a different perspective on the same thing.

Comment: @TravisJ: No one is objecting to your statement that "they are two different ways of looking at the same thing"; you don't need to defend it. The problem is with your contrast between "mathy" and "programatical"; they are *both* mathy. It's true that only one is of particular CS interest, but that's not relevant to mathematicians. (Your claim is like saying that 'good' and 'OK' are different perspectives, 'good' being kind of "Englishy" and 'OK' being more "Portuguesical", because Portuguese has borrowed only the latter.)

Comment: One difference is that $\exp(x)$ is certainly single valued, while $e^x$ may or may not be.

Comment: @Carl Mummert How so? I can't think of a time when $\exp(x)$ and $e^x$ were defined differently. In every case I can think of this is just variant notation (much like $\sin^{-1}(x)$ vs. $\mathrm{arcsin}(x)$).

Comment: @Bill Cook: $\exp(z)$ is universally defined by a power series (in my experience). Some authors define $e^z$ the same way, but others define $e^z = \exp(z \log(e))$, which is multivalued in the same way that $\log(z)$ is multivalued (in other words, they define $a^z$ in the same way for all nonzero complex $a$). I was able to find at least two examples of this by a quick Google books search.

Comment: @Carl Mummert Interesting. I definitely haven't noticed authors using such a distinction, but it actually quite a reasonable one. Thanks! :)

Comment: @CarlMummert I have never seen an author define $a^b=\exp(b\log a)$ without *also* specifying that the $\log a$ is to be taken on its principal branch for at least positive reals (conventions may differ elsewhere), so that you indeed have the equality $\exp x=e^x$ with no "phantom" branches. I don't see any usefulness in considering these branches as part of the "true" exponential function - but if you do, you will be obligated to add the inverses to these to the $\log$ function, which adds more branches to $\exp$, and so on.

Comment: @Mario Carneiro: $\exp(z)$ defined from a power series has no branches, of course - it's an analytic function. If you look through various complex analysis texts, you will find it is quite common to define $a^b$ in terms of an arbitrary branch of the logarithm (of course, the principal value is usually also defined). Few books make any special provision for when $a$ is positive real; they just define $a^b$ for all $b$ and nonzero $a$ in the same way.

Comment: @CarlMummert Of course, if you actually *pick* a branch of the logarithm (assuming the branch you pick includes the principal branch for positive reals - and any reasonable branch choice will do this), then $\exp(x)$ (by which I mean the single-valued power series) will match with $e^x$. But this also produces branch cuts for most complex $a$, and if you attempt to use the "multivalued function" approach to avoid making a choice, then you are left with "phantom" branches in $e^x$. (Part of the reason why I prefer to avoid contradictory "multivalued functions" in the first place.)

Answer (score 40):

Yes. The purpose for the notation $\exp$ is twofold:

- It allows one to talk about the exponentiation function itself, without specifying a particular input. For example, one can write that $\exp$ is a homomorphism from the additive group on $\mathbb{R}$ to the multiplicative group on $\mathbb{R}$. One may also say that $\exp$ and $\log$ are inverses.
- It allows you to write exponentiation without pushing the body of exponentiation into a superscript. For example, one may write the following, which is unwieldy to write without $\exp$ notation:

$$\prod_i e^{x_i} = \exp \sum_i x_i$$

Comment: Allow me to add to your last line that most physicists do not come across situations where $e$ might be ambiguous and therefore they use $e$ for exponentials (except when the argument gets too long).

Comment: Yes, I'm with @Hrodelbert: the statement that "exp" is preferred in physics seems unjustified.

Comment: Watch out, log(x) might resolve to log10(x) [or even log2(x)], not ln(x).

Comment: @Hrodelbert That last line was edited in. Removed it

Comment: Exp is a homomorphiam from the additive to the multiplicative. You've written it backwards.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 23):

As other answers say, in your homework (and, indeed, in most places in mathematics) there is no difference.

I have seen a beginning textbook first defining a certain function $\exp(x)$, then proving certain properties of it, and finally using those properties to motivate calling it $e^x$.

Comment: That's how I "learned" about the exponential function in our maths lectures. We first introduced exp(x) as the power series then proved that this equals some constant to the power of x and than defined that constant as e.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1226097/119385) [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1226100/119385) answers, but I want to add one thing: Well defines.

$e$ is some (positive) number, so (without knowing the function $\exp$), you can compute $e^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ – just multiply $e$ $n$ times with itself. You can also compute $e^{-n} = \frac{1}{e^n}$ and even $e^\frac{p}{q} = \sqrt[q] e^p$ (for $n, q \in \mathbb{N}, p \in \mathbb{Z}$). One can prove that the $\exp$ function yields the same numbers with these arguments. This justifies the notation.

Answer (score 6):

Although I agree with the answers already provided that in this situation (and indeed in most other ones in mathematics) there is no difference between the two notations, I would like to add the following for completeness:

In manifold theory (most particularly Lie Group theory or Riemannian geometry), the exponential map $\exp$ is a map from a tangent space to the manifold itself. For Lie groups, it expresses the local group structure and allows to lift many problems from the group to the tangent space (the Lie algebra). It also defines integral curves on the manifold and is therefore related to geodesics (which is more obvious from the viewpoint of Riemannian geometry).

This exponential $\exp$ coincides with the usual exponential for the case of the Lie group $\mathbb{R}$. It also coincides with the definition of the matrix exponential 
$$
e^A = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^n}{n!}.
$$
However, I believe this cannot be done in general, although I do not have an example available.

Comment: I am a bit surprised be the final sentence. Can you give an example of situation where $e^t$ is defined but different from $\exp(t)$?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen No I cannot. I guess what I remembered is that for disconnected Lie groups, $\exp$ does not cover the entire group, implying that not all group elements have an exponential representation. This, as you rightly question, has nothing to do with the mapping $t\mapsto e^t$. Nevertheless, I presume there do exist Lie groups for which the exponential mapping cannot be interpreted as a version of the map $t\mapsto e^t$, are there not?

Comment: Yes, there are non-linear Lie groups, groups that cannot be embedded in any $GL(n,\Bbb R)$, and they still have an $\exp$ map, but writing $e^t$ is problematic as it cannot be defined as a matrix exponential. By the way I think the notion of $\exp$ is just more general, and one could do away with the notation $e^x$ (and the cumbersome constant $e$) altogether by always writing $\exp(x)$ instead; for instance in case of a matrix exponential $\exp(A)$ seems much less confusing to me than $e^A$.

Comment: I agree with your statement that $\exp$ is simply more general. I guess that was the main point I was trying to convey here. Thank you for your comments, they were enlightening.

Answer (score 3):

While both expressions are generally the same, $\exp(x)$ is well-defined for a really large slurry of argument domains via its series: $x$ can be complex, imaginary, or even quadratic matrices.

The basic operation of exponentiation implicated by writing $e^x$ tends to have ickier definitions, like having to think about branches when writing $e^{1\over2}$ or at least generally $a^b$.

Exponentiation can be replaced by using $\exp$ and $\ln$ together via $a^b=\exp(b\ln a)$, and the ambiguities arise from the $\ln$ part of the replacement.  So it can be expedient to work with just $\exp$ when the task does not require anything else.  Informally, $e^x$ is used equivalently to $\exp(x)$ anyway but the latter is really more fundamental and well-defined.

Comment: Are you saying $e^x$ is defined over a smaller range than $\exp(x)$, for instance that the former is not defined when $x$ is complex? If so, have you evidence for that? I thought $e^{i\pi} = -1$ was a reasonably well known identity.

Comment: @abligh Carl Mummert [points out](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226089/is-expx-the-same-as-ex#comment2498621_1226097) that if you interpret $e^x$ as $\exp(x\log e)$ and are not careful with the branch of log, you can get undesirable results such as $e^{i\pi}=-\exp(2n\pi^2)$ for any $n\in\Bbb Z$. Although "multivalued functions" can sometimes be useful, we don't want that sort of thing to happen in the definition of $\exp$ since it is already analytic.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason we use $\exp(x)$ is when defining it in terms of its power series. At that point, we don't know that $\exp(x)=e^x$ when $x$ is real.

Also, there are general problems using the notation $a^z$ when $z$ is complex. 
$a^z$ is actually a multi-valued function. $e^z$ is thus sometimes ambiguous, so we will, in those cases, prefer $\exp(z)$ to clarify that we are talking about the single-valued function.

Comment: Why would $a^z$ be multivalued? If $a>0$, we define $a^z = e^{z \cdot \log a}$.

Comment: What if $a$ isn't real? @goblin To write $x^y$ in general, you require multivalued functions or some horrible branch cut.

Comment: Being real isn't strong enough; we want $a \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Otherwise, you don't write $a^z$ without explaining to your reader explicitly what your notation means. If $a$ isn't in $\mathbb{R}_{>0},$ I would advocate writing $a^z_\mathbf{C}$ for whatever version of the exponential you need, where $a^z_\mathbf{C}$ is interpreted as $\mathbf{C}(a,z)$ and $\mathbf{C}$ is understood to be a 2-place function.

Comment: But that's my point, $a^z$ is ambiguous, in general, depending on which branch of $\log a$ you take. As I said, it is a multi-valued function.

Comment: The optimal convention surely is that $a^z$ is unambiguous, we only write $a^z$ when $a>0$, and we decorate the notation in some way whenever we want to extend so that $a$ can be a negative or complex number.

Comment: I'm glad you've written an optimation routine for us, @goblin I'm sure you can prove correctness.

Answer (score 1):

$e^x$ is the same as $\exp\left(x\right)$. However, parts of math which deal with more abstract or complex structures (like matrices), you tend to use $\exp\left(x\right)$ instead of $e^x$.

For example, taking $e^M$ for a matrix makes no sense as it does for real numbers, but taking $\exp\left(M\right)$ for a matrix makes perfect sense and is well defined.

$$\exp\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{x^0}{0!}+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{5^2}{5!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}\dots$$

While we can say $e^x$ = $\exp\left(x\right)$ and use that as a new definition of $e^x$, using $exp\left(x\right)$ makes it clearer that we're looking for the taylor series instead of trying to find some sort of meaning to raising $e$ to the power of $M$.

Answer (score 0):

We use exp(Θ) for discrete values. Matlab can only use exp() because everything is discrete in it. In reality, you can use e^Θ in your algebra because continuous.

You can still consider (exp^(jΘ)-e^(jΘ)) / 2j  to be a sin if you want discrete values.